# Unable to combine MLS and mesh generation in one file

Tags: pcl, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am able to do MLS and then also generate mesh, but I need to do both of them separately. I am not able to find a way to do it in one go. First I do MLS and save the file. And then read that file again and generate mesh.

If I combine both I am encountering segmentation fault. The code does MLS successfully but than fails.
The two tutorials which I tried to combine are:

Greedy projection : http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/greedy_projection.php#greedy-triangulation

and

MLS : http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/resampling.php#moving-least-squares

Also since MLS itself compute the surface normal so I commented the part of the code where normal are generated.

Any help of pointers is greatly appreciated.

Let me know if I ask PCL related questions somewhere else?

My combined code is:

```
int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "seg"); //is the third param node name
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  int p_setKSearch = 20;
  double p_setSearchRadius = 0.025;
  double p_setMu = 2.5;

  double p_neighbours = 100;
  double p_maxSurfAnglePiDiv = 4; // 45 degrees
  double p_minAnglePiDiv =18; // 10 degrees

  double p_maxAnglePiDiv = 1.5; // 120 degrees
  bool p_normal_consist = false;
  std::string p_pcd_file = "/home/aknirala/chair.pcd";

  double lDv;   //Loaded double value
  int lIv;
  bool lBv;
  std::string lSv;

  std::cout<<"\n Getting the parameters...............";
  if(nh.getParam("/mesh/meshParam/p_setKSearch", lIv))          p_setKSearch = lIv;
  if(nh.getParam("/mesh/meshParam/p_setSearchRadius", lDv))     p_setSearchRadius = lDv;
  if(nh.getParam("/mesh/meshParam/p_setMu", lDv))               p_setMu = lDv;

  if(nh.getParam("/mesh/meshParam/p_neighbours", lDv))          p_neighbours = lDv;
  if(nh.getParam("/mesh/meshParam/p_maxSurfAnglePiDiv", lDv))   p_maxSurfAnglePiDiv = lDv;
  if(nh.getParam("/mesh/meshParam/p_minAnglePiDiv", lDv))       p_minAnglePiDiv = lDv;

  if(nh.getParam("/mesh/meshParam/p_maxAnglePiDiv", lDv))       p_maxAnglePiDiv = lDv;
  if(nh.getParam("/mesh/meshParam/p_normal_consist", lBv))      p_normal_consist = lBv;
  if(nh.getParam("/mesh/sourceFile", lSv))      p_pcd_file = lSv;

  std::cout<<"\n p_setKSearch : "<<p_setKSearch;
  std::cout<<"\n p_setSearchRadius : "<<p_setSearchRadius;
  std::cout<<"\n p_setMu : "<<p_setMu;

  std::cout<<"\n p_neighbours : "<<p_neighbours;
  std::cout<<"\n p_maxSurfAnglePiDiv : "<<p_maxSurfAnglePiDiv;
  std::cout<<"\n p_minAnglePiDiv : "<<p_minAnglePiDiv;

  std::cout<<"\n p_maxAnglePiDiv : "<<p_maxAnglePiDiv;
  std::cout<<"\n p_normal_consist : "<<p_normal_consist;
  std::cout<<"\n p_pcd_file : "<<p_pcd_file;

  // Load input file into a PointCloud<T> with an appropriate type
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud_blob;
  pcl::io::loadPCDFile (p_pcd_file, cloud_blob);
  pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2 (cloud_blob, *cloud);     //What exactly is being converted here?
                                                     //cloud_blob may not be of type XYZ :-)
  //* the data should be available in cloud
  //Convert a PCLPointCloud2 binary data blob ---> into a pcl::PointCloud<T> object
  //Oh, so this is one of the way to load any point cloud type from a pcd file, which we do not
  // know before reading the file to desired point type. IN this case, to PointXYZ.

 




  /*
  // Normal estimation*
  pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> n;
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr normals (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);
  pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  tree->setInputCloud (cloud);
  n.setInputCloud (cloud);
  n.setSearchMethod (tree);
  n.setKSearch (p_setKSearch);      //It was 20
  n.compute (*normals);             //Normals are estimated using standard method.
  //* normals should not contain the point normals + surface curvatures

  // Concatenate the XYZ and normal fields*
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>::Ptr cloud_with_normals (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>);
  pcl::concatenateFields (*cloud, *normals, *cloud_with_normals);
  //* cloud_with_normals = cloud + normals


*/


  //Here Normals are being generated and then merged. But MLA (moving least square) can do that in one go.
  pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>);

  // Output has the PointNormal type in order to store the normals calculated by MLS
   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal> mls_points;

   // Init object (second point type is for the normals, even if unused)
   pcl::MovingLeastSquares<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointNormal> mls;

   mls.setComputeNormals (true);

   // Set parameters
   mls.setInputCloud (cloud);   //of type xyz
   mls.setPolynomialFit (true);
   mls.setSearchMethod (tree);
   mls.setSearchRadius (p_setSearchRadius);     //original was 0.03

   // Reconstruct
   mls.process (mls_points);

   std::cout<<"\n MLS constructed.";
   pcl::io::savePCDFile ("bun0-mls.pcd", mls_points);
   std::cout<<"\n MLS written.";





   pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal>::Ptr mls_points_ptr (&mls_points);

   // Create search tree*
   pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointNormal>::Ptr tree2 (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointNormal>);
   tree2->setInputCloud (mls_points_ptr);

  // Initialize objects
  pcl::GreedyProjectionTriangulation<pcl::PointNormal> gp3;
  pcl::PolygonMesh triangles;

  // Set the maximum distance between connected points (maximum edge length)
  gp3.setSearchRadius (p_setSearchRadius);          //It was 0.025

  // Set typical values for the parameters
  gp3.setMu (p_setMu);                                          //It was 2.5
  gp3.setMaximumNearestNeighbors (p_neighbours);    //It was 100
  gp3.setMaximumSurfaceAngle(M_PI/p_maxSurfAnglePiDiv); // 45 degrees   //it was 4
  gp3.setMinimumAngle(M_PI/p_minAnglePiDiv); // 10 degrees      //It was 18
  gp3.setMaximumAngle(M_PI/p_maxAnglePiDiv); // 120 degrees     //it was 1.5
  gp3.setNormalConsistency(p_normal_consist);                   //It was false

  // Get result
  gp3.setInputCloud (mls_points_ptr);
  gp3.setSearchMethod (tree2);
  gp3.reconstruct (triangles);

  // Additional vertex information
  std::vector<int> parts = gp3.getPartIDs();
  std::vector<int> states = gp3.getPointStates();
  pcl::io::saveVTKFile ("/home/aknirala/mesh_Smooth.vtk", triangles);
  // Finish
  return (0);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187188/unable-to-combine-mls-and-mesh-generation-in-one-file/) by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2014-07-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-07-20**:
Just to know...exactly on which line, are you encountering the segmentation fault ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PCL has a mailing list that is probably more appropriate for this type of question: http://www.pcl-users.org/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0